# Проблема с проигрыванием звука с SDCard

Tags: android

Не проигрываются звуки с карты телефона в эмуляторе соответственно и почему-то на некоторых моделях. Вот ошибка, которую выдает инициализация каждого звука при старте приложения:

```
04-10 12:21:44.802: WARN/MediaPlayer(3651): info/warning (1, 26)
04-10 12:21:44.832: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource
04-10 12:21:44.832: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3651): error (1, -17)
04-10 12:21:44.842: WARN/System.err(3651): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
04-10 12:21:44.852: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
04-10 12:21:44.852: WARN/PlayerDriver(31): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
04-10 12:21:44.852: WARN/System.err(3651):     at com.example.util.AudioClass.<init>(AudioClass.java:28)
04-10 12:21:44.852: WARN/System.err(3651):     at com.example.SoundClass.getAudioClip(SoundClassjava:747)
04-10 12:21:44.862: WARN/System.err(3651):     at com.example.SoundClass.onCreate(SoundClass.java:113)
04-10 12:21:44.862: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 12:21:44.862: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-10 12:21:44.862: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-10 12:21:44.872: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-10 12:21:44.872: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-10 12:21:44.872: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 12:21:44.872: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 12:21:44.872: WARN/System.err(3651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-10 12:21:44.882: WARN/System.err(3651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 12:21:44.882: WARN/System.err(3651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 12:21:44.882: WARN/System.err(3651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-10 12:21:44.882: WARN/System.err(3651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-10 12:21:44.882: WARN/System.err(3651):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 12:21:44.902: DEBUG/Addon(3651): /sdcard/Directory/Pack/sound.mp3
```

Тут в конце я логирую и показываю что файл есть   
04-10 12:21:44.902: DEBUG/Addon(3651): /sdcard/Directory/Pack/sound.mp3

На моем Desire HD все работает

Файлы в проге подключаю так:

```
sound1 = getAudioClip("sound1.mp3"); 
sound2 = getAudioClip("sound2.mp3");
```

Вот код гета:

```
protected AudioClass getAudioClip(String FileName) 
{
    return new AudioClass(FileName, "Name");
}
```

Вот сам класc:

```
public class AudioClass
{
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private String name;

    private boolean mPlaying = false;
    private boolean mLoop = false;

    private String SDCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Directory/";

    public AudioClass(String FileName, String DirName) 
    {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try 
        {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(SDCardPath + AddonName + "/" + FileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Addon",SDCardPath + AddonName + "/" + FileName);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void start () 
    {
        mPlaying = true;
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            mLoop = false;
            if ( mPlaying ) { 
                mPlaying = false;
                mPlayer.pause();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("AduioClip::stop " + name + " " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public synchronized void loop () {
        mLoop = true;
        mPlaying = true;
        mPlayer.start();

    }

    public void release () {
        if (mPlayer != null) { 
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в какой момент создаётся экземпляр AudioClass? Может, он создаётся при создании приложения в какой-то "неудачный" момент, когда приложение ещё не готово? Кроме того, выполнение операций ввода-вывода в конструкторе - чертовски плохая идея.

Также меня насторожил текст из [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare%28%29):

> > After setting the datasource **and the display** surface, you need to either call prepare() or prepareAsync()